# What do film dates with Roman numerals after the year mean on IMDB?

Tags: production, distribution, imdb

Sometimes on IMDB I see films which are dated like this:

```
Sergio Corbucci:
Night Club ................. 1989/I

Robert Rodriguez:
The Black Mamba (Short) .... 2011/I
Two Scoops (Short) ......... 2013/II
```

> Screenshot:
>
> [image]
>
> Live links:
>
> - [To check Corbucci films](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0179281/)
> - [To check Rodriguez films](http://www.imdb.com/name/nm0001675/)

What does it mean? (This is my question.) I don't understand.

It doesn't seem to be a reference to the release date (1st half of the year, second half of the year), because:

```
Title                        Strange date    Release Date    
---------------------------------------------------------

Sergio Corbucci:
Night Club ................. 1989/I ....... 10 March 1989   

Robert Rodriguez:
The Black Mamba (Short) .... 2011/I ............. unknown
Two Scoops (Short) ......... 2013/II ........ 31 May 2013
```

As clearly shown here, Night Club was released in March and Two Scoops in May. March and May are both in the 1st half of the year, but the Roman numerals are different (I vs. II).

Comment: Could it be directors? Doesn't Two Scoops have two (LOL)?

Comment: @DarthLocke I don't think so. There are a lot of films co-directed by 2 or 3 or 4 directors, but their's dates haven't any roman numerals. By the the way, Night Club directed by only one director.

Comment: it was just a guess, but I see we have the real answer!

Comment: I thought the Roman numerals meant the quarter at first (i.e. I means in the first three months of the year etc) but apparently not. For instance, [this page](https://www.imdb.com/name/nm3065748/) mentions a film saying 2008/IV, but it was released on 6 march 2008. Oh well.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

## To distinguish between works with the same title and release date.

In your case, to distinguish between [Night Club](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0097978/?ref_=nv_sr_2), by Sergio Corbucci, and [Night Club](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0100250/releaseinfo?ref_=tt_ov_inf), by Michael Keusch. The same thing happens with Two Scoops, just check the [search link](http://www.imdb.com/find?ref_=nv_sr_fn&q=Two%20Scoops%202013&s=all).

This is explained in their [help page](https://help.imdb.com/article/contribution/titles/title-formatting/G56U5ERK7YY47CQB?ref_=helpsrsctn#), as pointed out by user [snow](https://movies.stackexchange.com/users/43022/snow).

> If two films have the same title in the same year we add a "/" followed by roman numerals after the year as necessary. For example, Twilight (2008/I) and Twilight (2008/II).

Comment: Is the reason it's in the date, and not some other field, because of the "Title (Year)" format of referencing films?

Comment: @ErinAnne I'm not certain, but possibly because it's less "Year" and more "Chronological ordering"?

Comment: I would guess that if it were in the title it could be mistaken with actual title numbering (Saw, Saw II, etc). On the date, its clearer, but im just guessing

Comment: IMDB help page on this subject [here](https://help.imdb.com/article/contribution/titles/title-formatting/G56U5ERK7YY47CQB?ref_=helpsrsctn#): *"If two films have the same title in the same year we add a "/" followed by roman numerals after the year as necessary"*